# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n}$$ converges for every $x>1$.

let $a(x)$ be the sum of the series. does $a$ continious at $x=2$? differentiable?

I guess the first part is with leibniz but I am not sure about it.

Comment: What convergence tests do you know?  Since this summand is a simple ratio, there is an "obvious" choice for a test to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the geometric series:

$$a(x) = \frac1{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n} = \frac{1}{x\left(1+\frac1x\right)} = \frac{1}{x+1}$$

Comment: why there is 1/x before the series?

Comment: @UltimateMath $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n} = \frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}} =  \frac1{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{x^n}\right|}=\dfrac{1}{|x|}<1$$
then the series is converge for $|x|>1$.

Comment: let a(x) be the sum of the series. does a continious at x=2? differentiable? any clue?

Comment: Clearly according to other answer, in $|x|>1$, the series converges to $\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ which is continous and differentiable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

What if you use the ratio test?$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the
partial sums,
and let $y = -1/x$
so
$-1 < y < 0$..

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(y)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (-1)^{n-1}(-y)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (-1)^{n-1}(-1)^ny^n\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{m} y^n\\
&=-y\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} y^n\\
&=-y\dfrac{1-y^m}{1-y}\\
&=\dfrac{-y}{1-y}-\dfrac{-y^{m+1}}{1-y}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(y)+\dfrac{y}{1-y}
&=\dfrac{y^{m+1}}{1-y}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n}+\dfrac{-1/x}{1+1/x}
=\dfrac{1}{(-x)^{m+1}(1+1/x)}
$
or
$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}
=\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{x^{m}(x+1)}
$.

What is needed now is
to show that
$\lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x^{m}(x+1)}
=0$.

(This is from
"What is Mathematics")

Since $x > 1$,
$x = 1+z$
where $z > 0$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$x^m
=(1+z)^m
\ge 1+mz
\gt mz
=m(x-1)$,
so
$ \dfrac{1}{x^{m}(x+1)}
\lt \dfrac{1}{m(x-1)(x+1)}
=\dfrac{1}{m(x^2-1)}
$,
so to make
$\dfrac{1}{x^{m}(x+1)}
\lt \epsilon
$
it is enough to take
$m
\gt \dfrac1{\epsilon(x^2-1)}
$.

This is certainly
not the best $m$,
but it is
completely elementary.